# Star Trek episode codes. Do all episodes have one?

Tags: star-trek

The reference work *Star Trek Concordance* gave every original and animated episode a unique code.

For instance:

- *The Doomsday Machine* → `DMa`
- *The Trouble With Tribbles* → `TT`
- *The Ambergris Element* → `Am/a` (notice the `/a` for *animated*)

Larry Nemecek later continued this *tradition* in his *Star Trek: The Next Generation Companion* but he exclusively used lowercase two-letter-codes:

- *The High Ground* code → `hi`
- *The Best of Both Worlds, Part II* → `b2`
- *The Big Goodbye* → `bg`

Are you aware of any other references works or else inventing a similar scheme?

And I am not talking about series/season/ordinal systems like `VOY 6×05` or `DS9 2×01` but rather a system based on title abbreviations.

Comment: That seems like a system that's inevitably going to lead to more and more ridiculous abbreviations in order to avoid conflicts with previous series and episodes.

Comment: Lowercase two-letter-codes with 26 standard letters will run out after 676 episodes. If you include digits 0-9 you have 36 symbols which means you can have 1296 different codes - it is very unlikely that everyone of them would make sense.